# 政府統計総合窓口（e-Stat）におけるurl内パラメータについて

Tags: python

過去20年のパソコン普及率をグラフ化するためe-Statから主要耐久消費財等の普及・保有状況という統計表のCSVファイルを一括ダウンロードしたいと考えています。
方法としては指定のurlをスクレイピングし，CSVファイルを取得したいと考えています。
まず以下に令和3年度，令和4年度のデータがあるurlを記載します。

https://www.e-stat.go.jp/stat-search/files?page=1&layout=datalist&toukei=00100405&tstat=000001014549&cycle=0&tclass1=000001149088&tclass2=000001153086&tclass3val=0

https://www.e-stat.go.jp/stat-search/files?page=1&layout=datalist&toukei=00100405&tstat=000001014549&cycle=0&tclass1=000001162554&tclass2=000001164846&tclass3val=0

この2つの違いはtclass1とtclass2の値であり，この値が提供分類1と提供分類2を示していることはわかっています。この値はどこの情報を参照すればわかりますでしょうか？

Comment: 自己解決できました。

Comment: デベロッパーツールで遷移前webサイトのhtml構造を確認したところ、data-key1，data-value1およびdata-key2，data-value2の値がtclass1とtclass2の値と同一であることが確認できました。質問が下手で申し訳ありません。